# How to overlap elements in css using grid

Tags: css, grid

I want to place `box 2` on top of both other boxes by half of them, however, even having explicitly defined `grid-template-columns` propriety to `1fr` it automatically creates another column.
Here is my attempt

index.html

```
<div class="grid-overlap">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

style.scss

```
.grid-overlap {
        max-width: 40rem;
        width: 95%;`your text`
        margin: 2rem auto;
        gap: 1rem;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;

        .box {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 3rem;
        }

        .box:nth-child(1) {
            grid-row: 1 / 3;
            background-color: dodgerblue;
        }
        .box:nth-child(2) {
            background-color: red;
            grid-row: 2 / 4;
            z-index: 100;
        }
        .box:nth-child(3) {
            grid-row: 3 / 5;
            background-color: tomato;
        }
    }
```

[image: I hope this image can give you the idea]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what effect you want as you have fixed the dimensions of each box in px units but have defined a maximum dimension of the overall grid in rem units. Which is the one to be used? And I don't understand why a gap is defined when none is shown in the picture you have given.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving one example of overlap, try to see how it works and use it in your use case.

```css
.grid-overlap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}
.grid-overlap .box:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.grid-overlap .box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  grid-row: 2/4;
  grid-column: 2/4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-overlap">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the grid we can see that the second square starts in the middle of the first one and that the last one is positioned at one quarter along and three quarters down the first square.

This leads to a grid of width 6 and height 7 square cells.

As it's not possible to have both the grid imensions set at 300px and the width of the grid to be defined in rems (and % units) this snippet drops the 300px settings and sets the overall grid to be the width as defined in the question and the aspect ratio 6/7.

Note that the grid gap is not set (defaults to 0) as no gap was shown in the picture given in the question.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-overlap {
  max-width: 40rem;
  width: 95%;
  aspect-ratio: 6 / 7;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  gap: 1rem;
  gap: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.box {
  /*width: 300px;
            height: 300px;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: 3 / span 4;
  grid-row: 3 / span 4;
  z-index: 100;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 2/ span 4;
  grid-row: 4 / span 4;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="grid-overlap">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If the important dimensions were the 300px then use those to set the width of the overall grid.